# Can/should environmental factors be assessed/exploited by geographic prevalence of disease for diagnosing/treating mysterious diseases?

Tags: environmental-conditions

"Environmental factors" are sometimes implicated in mysterious diseases. I think that probably goes without saying but in case that is not to be presumed I point to [this study](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/art.20534) as an example.

Is it possible that if a patient for a mysterious disease lives in a location where that disease is statistically prevalent might it be a plausible and warranted step in the diagnosis of the disease to move the patient from a geographic location where the disease is prevalent to one where it is unknown, even without understanding what are the relevant differences between the two environments? Would that not go a long way to "ruling out" environmental factors?

Environmental things "we know that we don't know":

- air
- water
- radon
- pollens

etc.

But I think this approach would be more important for the things that "we don't know that we don't know", which are always more elusive and abundant.

Comment: How do you go about moving people? They have jobs, families, homes. If you don't know what environmental factor might be the issue, where do you move them? And how long do you wait before concluding the move wasn't helpful? Months, years?

Comment: Putting an appropriate and agreeable/motivated patient (which might take some doing, admittedly) up in an apartment in a city with an appropriate level of care, carefully monitored created for that purpose as a proof of concept would be considerably simpler than a double-blind study, from what I understand. But perhaps they are fortunate to have an open door to someone in their own family who can provide the lodging and care. Stranger things have happened.

Comment: Also, is "differential-diagnosis" a relevant tag for this question?

Comment: No, differential diagnosis is not a relevant tag. What you're proposing can't arrive at a diagnosis since you'll have no idea what caused any change in the patient's condition.

Comment: I removed it, thanks.